# Using RVM with gvim without installing the ruby binary

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, ruby

In Arch Linux, apparently `gvim` requires to install ruby as a dependency. However, if I want to work with RVM, then I don't need the binary ruby installed.

Can that cause problems? Can ruby be removed and gvim configured to use the RVM version of ruby that's installed?

Note that trying sudo `pacman -Rs ruby` outputs an error:

```
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: gvim: requires ruby
```

Any tips?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would care whether or not the ruby binary is installed (seeing as how RVM "allows you to easily install, manage, and work with *multiple* ruby environments"). Presumably the dependancy is for scripting vim itself (it probably has perl and python as dependencies too) and that the compiled parts of gvim should work with whatever ruby is available to it...so go ahead and try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option #1

You'll need to recompile `gvim` to remove the requirement. It's configurable when building it.

This post I wrote on my blog shows how to compile Ruby support in, but you could just as easily remove it. **NOTE:** this post is Fedora/RHEL specific so it's not a template of steps for you to follow, but just to show you that it is possible to recompile `gvim` with/without Ruby support if you so choose.

Incidentally I think the issue you're running into is that the package manger knows that `gvim` "requires" and is enforcing this when you try to remove it.

#### Option #2

You could override the package manager and "force" the removal if you know no other packages require it.

#### Option #3

A 3rd options would be to install the Ruby package, and RVM. When you setup RVM you're overriding your $PATH, so RVM's versions of Ruby are the precedent, even though you have Ruby installed as a package on the system.

So your RVM's Ruby should be the one that `gvim` is using anyways.

For example:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/saml/apps/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/saml/apps/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.0/bin:/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/home/saml/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/home/saml/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/home/saml/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/brlcad/bin:/home/saml/bin:/usr/brlcad/bin

$ which ruby
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
```

Here you can see that when `ruby` is invoked, my RVM version is the one getting picked up. Unless `vim/gvim` has the path to `ruby` hardcoded (I doubt this) then it's bound by the same search through your `$PATH`, so it will find the RVM ruby too.

Comment: I'd go with option 3 and use the distro gvim.  Compiling it from source can be a little painstaking WRT the X dependencies (here's my note about it tho, verbatim: "Intrinsic.h in libxt; imake (make for X11);
libxpm".  The `.configure` script is not that friendly ;)

Comment: @goldilocks - thanks, I use option #3 as well, every day.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Arch's ABS (Arch Build System) to reconfigure the gvim package and remove the Ruby dependency.  The Arch Wiki has a pretty detailed page about the ABS.

Once you've done that, you'll probably want to add `IgnorePkg = gvim` to your `/etc/pacman.conf` file to prevent pacman from overwriting your customised version the next time you update the system.